# In FastAPI Getting 'Not authenticated' Error after authenticate

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, jwt, fastapi, bearer-token

## File dir

> fastapi_jwt
>
> > .env
> > main.py
> > app
> >
> > > api.py
> > > model.py
> > > auth
> > >
> > > > auth_bearer.py
> > > > auth_handler.py

---

#### fastapi_jwt/.env

```
secret=please_please_update_me_please
algorithm=HS256
```

---

#### fastapi_jwt/main.py

```
import uvicorn

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("app.api:app", host="127.0.0.1", port=8000, reload=True)
```

---

#### fastapi_jwt/app/api.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Body, Depends
from starlette.responses import HTMLResponse

from app.model import PostSchema, UserSchema, UserLoginSchema
from app.auth.auth_bearer import JWTBearer
from app.auth.auth_handler import signJWT

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/", tags=["root"])
async def read_root():
    return {"message": "Welcome to your blog!."}

from app.model import PostSchema

posts = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Pancake",
        "content": "Lorem Ipsum ..."
    }
]

users = []

@app.get("/posts", tags=["posts"])
async def get_posts() -> dict:
    return { "data": posts }


@app.get("/posts/{id}", tags=["posts"])
async def get_single_post(id: int) -> dict:
    if id > len(posts):
        return {
            "error": "No such post with the supplied ID."
        }

    for post in posts:
        if post["id"] == id:
            return {
                "data": post
            }
@app.get("/post", dependencies=[Depends(JWTBearer())], tags=["posts"])
@app.post("/post", dependencies=[Depends(JWTBearer())], tags=["posts"])
async def add_post(post: PostSchema) -> dict:
    post.id = len(posts) + 1
    posts.append(post.dict())
    return {"result":"Post added successfully"}

@app.post("/user/signup", tags=["user"])
async def create_user(user: UserSchema = Body(...)):
    users.append(user) # replace with db call, making sure to hash the password first
    return signJWT(user.email)

def check_user(data: UserLoginSchema):
    for user in users:
        if user.email == data.email and user.password == data.password:
            return True
    return False

@app.post("/user/login", tags=["user"])
async def user_login(user: UserLoginSchema = Body(...)):
    if check_user(user):
        return signJWT(user.email)
    return {
        "error": "Wrong login details!"
    }
```

---

#### fastapi_jwt/app/model.py

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, EmailStr
    
    
    class PostSchema(BaseModel):
        id: int = Field(default=None)
        title: str = Field(...)
        content: str = Field(...)
    
        class Config:
            schema_extra = {
                "example": {
                    "title": "Securing FastAPI applications with JWT.",
                    "content": "In this tutorial, you'll learn how to secure your application by enabling authentication using JWT. We'll be using PyJWT to sign, encode and decode JWT tokens...."
                }
            }    
    class UserSchema(BaseModel):
        fullname: str = Field(...)
        email: EmailStr = Field(...)
        password: str = Field(...)
    
        class Config:
            schema_extra = {
                "example": {
                    "fullname": "Abdulazeez Abdulazeez Adeshina",
                    "email": "abdulazeez@x.com",
                    "password": "weakpassword"
                }
            }
    
    class UserLoginSchema(BaseModel):
        email: EmailStr = Field(...)
        password: str = Field(...)
    
        class Config:
            schema_extra = {
                "example": {
                    "email": "abdulazeez@x.com",
                    "password": "weakpassword"
                }
            }
```

---

#### fastapi_jwt/app/auth/auth_bearer.py

```
from fastapi import Request, HTTPException
from fastapi.security import HTTPBearer, HTTPAuthorizationCredentials

from .auth_handler import decodeJWT


class JWTBearer(HTTPBearer):
    def __init__(self, auto_error: bool = True):
        super(JWTBearer, self).__init__(auto_error=auto_error)

    async def __call__(self, request: Request):
        credentials: HTTPAuthorizationCredentials = await super(JWTBearer, self).__call__(request)
        if credentials:
            if not credentials.scheme == "Bearer":
                raise HTTPException(status_code=403, detail="Invalid authentication scheme.")
            if not self.verify_jwt(credentials.credentials):
                raise HTTPException(status_code=403, detail="Invalid token or expired token.")
            return credentials.credentials
        else:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=403, detail="Invalid authorization code.")

    def verify_jwt(self, jwtoken: str) -> bool:
        isTokenValid: bool = False

        try:
            payload = decodeJWT(jwtoken)
        except:
            payload = None
        if payload:
            isTokenValid = True
        return isTokenValid
```

---

#### fastapi_jwt/app/auth/auth_handler.py

```
import time
from typing import Dict

import jwt
from decouple import config


JWT_SECRET = config("secret")
JWT_ALGORITHM = config("algorithm")


def token_response(token: str):
    return {
        "access_token": token
    }

def signJWT(user_id: str) -> Dict[str, str]:
    payload = {
        "user_id": user_id,
        "expires": time.time() + 600
    }
    token = jwt.encode(payload, JWT_SECRET, algorithm=JWT_ALGORITHM)

    return token_response(token)

def decodeJWT(token: str) -> dict:
    try:
        decoded_token = jwt.decode(token, JWT_SECRET, algorithms=[JWT_ALGORITHM])
        return decoded_token if decoded_token["expires"] >= time.time() else None
    except:
        return {}
```

I run 'main.py', the url
" http://127.0.0.1:8000/post " shows the output "{"detail":"Not authenticated"}".
So go to the url " http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs " for FastAPI -Swagger UI interface like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMqs6.png).
Then I signup and login to get the jwt token and use that token to [authenticate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qo21M.png), then go to url
" /post " in FastAPI -Swagger UI and execute to get the output [{"result": "Post added successfully"}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ftJU.png).
But in " http://127.0.0.1:8000/post " got an error and show the same ouput "{"detail":"Not authenticated"}"

Comment: How are you including the JWT header when you go directly to `/post` in your browser? The access method (i.e. whether through javascript, opening it directly in the browser, etc.) will need to supply the correct credentials. This does not happen automagically unless you're basing the authentication on cookies that have been set in the same domain.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).